# How to show specific datepickers with full dateformat?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have four different datepickers, which they all work, but on Date1/Date2 which I can choose the month/day/year it only outputs month/year.

How can I get these two datepicker to show the date like mm/dd/yyyy?

https://jsfiddle.net/km96dgsd/

```
$(function() {
     $('.date-picker').datepicker(
                    { yearRange: "1980:",
                        dateFormat: "mm/yy",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        showButtonPanel: true,
                        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {


                            function isDonePressed(){              return ($('#ui-datepicker-div').html().indexOf('ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all ui-state-hover') > -1);
                            }

                            if (isDonePressed()){
                                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1)).trigger('change');

                                 $('.date-picker').focusout()//Added to remove focus from datepicker input box on selecting date
                            }
                        },
                        beforeShow : function(input, inst) {

                            inst.dpDiv.addClass('month_year_datepicker')



                            if ( $(input).is("#startDate2") || $(input).is("#startDate4") ) {
                                inst.dpDiv.addClass("hide-calendar");
                            }
                            else {
                                inst.dpDiv.removeClass("hide-calendar");
                            }
                        }
                    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could wrap this in an `each` loop and set format based on conditional

```
$('.date-picker').each(function() {
    var $input = $(this),
      useDays = $input.is('#startDate1, #startDate2'),
      dateFormat = useDays ? 'mm/dd/yy' : 'mm/yy';

    $input.datepicker({
      yearRange: "1980:",
      dateFormat: dateFormat,
      // .....
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/km96dgsd/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: but Date2/Date4 are different from Date1/Date3

Comment: then I don't understand your question and what it is you are exactly trying to do. You said you wanted different formats for 1 & 2 vs 3 & 4

Comment: well for date1/date2 i would like the dateformat mm/dd/yyyy and date3/date4 format mm/yyyy

Comment: well that's what my demo is doing is it not?